# How to position Dialog to top in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently creating a popup dialog. However, my dialog is positioned  popping up in the center.

How do I make the position at the very top of the page when I press the popup btn?

Here is my code

```
      <div>
      <div id="so_reg" className="buy_btn" onClick={this.onClickCashBuy.bind(this)}>
         Pop up button
        </div>
         <Dialog className="dialog" modal={false} open={this.state.buy_cash_popup} onRequestClose={this.onClickBuyCashCancel} style={{color: 'green'}} >
               <Test product={{price: this.state.buy_cash_type}} />
      </Dialog>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can override the style of **scrollPaper** in `<Dialog />`

#### Functional component

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  scrollPaper: {
    alignItems: 'baseline'  // default center
  }
});
```

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

#### Classical component

```
const styles = theme => createStyles({
  scrollPaper: {
    alignItems: 'baseline'  // default center
  }
});
```

```
const { classes } = props;
```

```
export default withStyles(styles)(YourComponent);
```

---

#### Usage

```
<Dialog classes={{scrollPaper: classes.scrollPaper }}>
```

---

Refer: document of Material-UI [Dialog CSS API](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)

The HTML structure of Dialog which we can see from dev tools

Choose the **MuiDialog-scrollPaper** from below

```html
<div
  class="MuiDialog-container MuiDialog-scrollPaper makeStyles-dialog-163"
  role="none presentation"
  tabindex="-1"
  style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;"
>
  <div
    class="MuiPaper-root MuiDialog-paper MuiDialog-paperScrollPaper MuiDialog-paperWidthSm MuiPaper-elevation24 MuiPaper-rounded"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
  >
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

In your code

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const styles = theme => createStyles({ // change to this
    scrollPaper: {
      alignItems: 'baseline'
    }
});

class Shop extends Component {
  render(){

const { classes } = this.props;  // add this

  return(
<Dialog className="dialog" classes={{scrollPaper: classes.scrollPaper }} modal={false} open={this.state.buy_cash_popup} onRequestClose={this.onClickBuyCashCancel} style={{color: 'green'}} >
 <Test product={{price: this.state.buy_cash_type}} />
 </Dialog>
export default withStyles(styles)(Shop);  // `styles` here rather than `class`
```

Comment: I tried following your advice but it still didnt work. I am using components so i tried translating your code into component structure. I updated my post. Let me know if you know how to fix it. thanks! :)

Comment: I updated the post again. I changed the makeStyles with withStyles. However, im getting an error: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'classes' of object '#<Object>'"

Comment: I tried using your updated version. I am not getting any errors however, it is still showing up in the middle of the screen instead of the top. Also, im assuming you write `const { classes } = this.props;` inside the render() function? (since props is undefined outside of the class component.

Comment: weird.. I'm getting no errors but the dialog is still popping up at the very centre when I click the button. Also, in my code I think its suppose to be `=this.props` instead of `=props`. And also, what is the point of using "theme"? I dont think its used anywhere

Comment: Okay I will investigate futher. Thank you for your help! @keikai